# QGIS: Layer shows up multiple times in Vector Join menu

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I've noticed that sometimes in QGIS a layer will be duplicated or triplicated in the layer selection sub-menu of the `Vector Join` menu. In the example below there is only a single instance of the `TER` layer in the layers panel.

Any thoughts on why this happens and how to fix it?

[image: example]